# NodeJS update. PATH how to change env variable?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I am trying to update node I updated it with the command 
 `sudo n latest`
previous version was **8.10.0**
latest version is **12.10.1**

But when I look-up for the version of the node. It shows me the previous version. And asks to change the PATH variable to the new version.

So my question is, how should I change the PATH?? How to execute this on the terminal? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: did you try it with starting new instance of the shell. You are still in the same shell, where you upgraded the node version. See the last line in your screenshot

Comment: Thankyou sir Umar. I got it.